# Record Count for different custom views

Tags: mysql, algorithm, data-structures, memcached, redis

I'm trying to solve a problem for getting the records count for different custom view's for a list view.The custom view is a user defined view which will have some added criteria's.

**Example :**

```
  All Records View(3): {criteria : none}
   Name |email       |age  
   John |john@foo.com| 23
   Ann  |ann@foo.com | 20
   Jack |jack@foo.com| 13


  Kids View(1): {criteria : age<15}
   Name |email       |age  
   Jack |jack@foo.com| 13

  Foo Kids View(1): {criteria : age<15 and email contains('foo.com')}
   Name |email       |age  
   Jack |jack@foo.com| 13
```

As given in the above example depending on the criteria the view count has to be calculated for each view.The counts for each view has be shown even before user selects a particular view.There are multiple user's viewing the record's/adding/updating /deleting records.Running a mysql query each time to display the count for each view can be really intensive and time consuming since there can be millions of rows.I have thought about using memcached or redis to store the initial record count of view and later on updating them when changes occur.The problem here is how to find out which requests is for which view dynamically at runtime.

Example: if 'Jacks' record is deleted from any view count must be subtracted in all view's , similarly if his age is updated to 20 then the count must be subtracted from kid's view and foo kid's view.

Any suggestion on how to tackle the problem is welcome..

Comment: It's not really clear what is the problem. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev:i'm sorry what part did u not understand?

Comment: Emil: the "which requests is for which view dynamically at runtime" part.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev : I have written an example for the scenario.pls check.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: caching. Cache record counts somewhere (memcached, redis) and run a cron job periodically that will refresh counters. Use this method if you don't care too much if your counters are slightly inaccurate.

Option 2: Store routing logic in your code. Your language might or might not make it easy. This is how it may look in Ruby:

```
class ViewMatcher
  def initialize
    @views = {'all' => lambda{|params| true },

              'kids' => lambda{|params| params[:age] && params[:age] < 15 },

              'foo kids' => lambda{|params| params[:age] && 
                                            params[:age] < 15 && 
                                            params[:email] && 
                                            params[:email].include?('foo')}}
  end

  def print_matching_views(params)
    puts "Matching views for query: #{params.inspect}"
    result = []
    @views.each do |k, v|
      result << k if v.call(params)
    end
    puts result
    puts ""
  end
end


vm = ViewMatcher.new

vm.print_matching_views :age => 10
vm.print_matching_views :age => 20
vm.print_matching_views :age => 10, :email => 'foo@example.com'
vm.print_matching_views :age => 10, :email => 'moo@example.com'
```

Output:

```
Matching views for query: {:age=>10}
all
kids

Matching views for query: {:age=>20}
all

Matching views for query: {:age=>10, :email=>"foo@example.com"}
all
kids
foo kids

Matching views for query: {:age=>10, :email=>"moo@example.com"}
all
kids
```

Comment: Thanks ,i'm using java.I'll have to see how the second solution is to be implemented in java.

Comment: @Emil: can't help you there, I am not very good in java. But it is certainly doable (though it might look uglier :-) ).